# How to save people with multiple names in database and keep search fast?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to parse a table of names, create a mysql table for them and insert them. Some people have 2 or maybe even more first names/last names. The file only has full names as long strings and no information where the first name stops and last name begins. Initially I wanted to create only 2 VARCHAR fields but now I am not sure anymore. Should I go with 1 field and FULLTEXT index on it instead? I want to be able to search fast by individual first or last names. I use 10.1.38 MariaDB.

Comment: "...and no information where the first name stops and last name begins..." -- Then, create a single column.

Comment: without a way to separate out first names and last names, if all i have is a single string, then i'm going to preserve that in the database as a single string. as far as searching, if i didn't want to go fulltext, and i was going to do matches to full terms, then i'd consider adding a child table, with parsed substrings, e.g. given fullname `id=42 fullname='five six pickup sticks'`  then i could store four rows in the child table `(42,'five',0),(42,'six',1),(42,'pickup',2),(42,'sticks',3)` and then search the child table for matching terms

Comment: If you're worried your ideal database design might be slow, test it. If it is slow, come back here, share your table structure, queries and output of EXPLAIN SELECT to get recommendations for improvements. It also matters if you have 1K records, 1M or 1G.

Comment: List the queries (`SELECTs`/`UPDATEs`) that need to understand the column in question.  That is, Optimization is based on operations, not schema.